# Chinese money plant- Overwatered?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, watering

My Chinese money plant is showing signs of overwatering (leaves curling under), but I only water it when the soil is bone dry all the way to the bottom of the pot. Is there potentially another issue? Could this a symptom of underfeeding or hard water? Some of my other sub-tropical plants are also curling under or getting brown scarring on the leaves.

The soil dries out about once every week and a half. My room retains heat very well, and generally the plant gets a lot of indirect light near to floor-ceiling window. The pot drains well. Just in case while looking into the issue, I’ve moved it under a plant light and placed the pot on a paper towel to draw out any additional moisture.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if your plant is suffering from a bit of drought; whilst it's important not to overwater, these plants do not  like to dry out completely, and if you are waiting till it's dry right through, that's too long between waterings. Water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, and water well, allowing the excess to drain away freely from the base of the pot. Make sure you empty any outer pot or tray it's standing in 30 minutes after watering if water has collected there, it's important to make sure  the base of the pot is not left sitting in water. Water again the same way ongoing, waiting till the surface of the soil feels  dry to the touch and the pot feels quite light in weight when you pick it up, but don't wait till it's so dry the soil is shrunken from the sides of the pot. As for light, bright, indirect light is best - from your description of your window, it does not sound as if a grow light is necessary, unless  the plant is in a dark corner somewhere; position it so it's getting good daylight instead. https://forest.london/blogs/plant-of-the-month/chinese-money-plant-plant-of-the-week